# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 from USB - low-graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, usb, graphics

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.03.3 64bit from USB.
I have downloaded the .iso file from ubuntu and with the help of unetbootin I brought it to my USB device. After restarting my computer and starting from USB I choose "Install Ubuntu". It takes about 1-2 minutes until I get this message:

"The System is running in low-grapgics mode - Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."

After clicking on "ok", I am given the following choices:

- Run in low-graphics mode for just one session
- Reconfigure graphics
- Troubleshoot the error
- Exit to console login

I tried to run it in low-graphics mode but then nothing happened. I also tried to install the newest version of nvidia driver in the terminal but I cannot manage to download the driver within the terminal and change it back again to the installation and after every restart the same problem is there.

My graphics-card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation. I have Asrock Z87 ITX motherboard, Intel 4690S processor and Asus GTX750Ti.

My system already had Ubuntu 14.04 on a small SSD and Windows 10 on a big HDD. I installed bigger mSATA SSD 512GB and wanted to use this chance to make a fresh Ubuntu installation after 18 months of 14.04 LTS updates and after my Hardware enablement update went wrong.

My solution was to take the graphics card out (it is not integrated, like it might be in a laptop). I am using UEFI BIOS without secure boot.

All attempts to use "nomodeset" or "acpi=off" or "nolapic" were not successful (any combination of previous options always ended with a "low-graphic mode error").

Without nVidia graphic card in the system, Ubuntu 14.04 installation was a breeze. Shutdown, put nVidia graphics card back into the system and reconnect the monitor cable. The only issue is what to do after a reboot.

One option is to use "nomodeset". When the system boots, and shows grub menu (use shift key if it does not), select 'e' in order to open edit mode and add "nomodeset". Start Ubuntu, login into the new installation and set the option permanently in /etc/default/grub file. Add "nomodeset" like in this line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

After modifying the file, run "sudo update-grub" in order to apply the change.

This solution worked for me. I am not getting "low-graphics error" anymore.